# Proving that in a Group the inverse of the inverse of an element is the element itself

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$. But a statement is confusing (Please see the highlighted portion in the image. I tried to type in the equation but its not working.)

How can we say that the inverse*(inverse of the inverse) is equal to the identity element?

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: This is wrong, unless $a^{-1}=a.$ BTW, add `$` signs before and after the equations can produce the formulae.

Comment: The highlighted row does **not** say that the inverse of the inverse is equal to the inverse; it says that the inverse of the inverse is the inverse of the inverse...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  well,how does it become equal to the identity element that is my question.

Comment: $(a^{-1})^{-1} \cdot a^{-1} = e$ because $a^{-1} \in G$, because the inverse of an elemet of $G$ is in $G$; thus, $a^{-1}$ has an inverse : $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ and by def of inverse, the product of an element and its inverse is $e$, i.e. $(a^{-1})^{-1} \cdot a^{-1} = e$ .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA where did you get $(a^{−1})^{−1}=e$

Comment: @awllower are you sure its wrong?

Comment: Edited the question to make it clear

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA oops i wanted to add the full proof,can you add your edit again please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ because $a^{-1} * a = a *a^{-1} = e$. Hence $a^{-1}*(a^{-1})^{-1} = a^{-1} *  a = e$ etc.

Maybe this makes it more clear: Write $b:=a^{-1}$. Then we try to prove that $b*a = a*b = e$ so that $b^{-1} = a$.

Comment: Please see the question,i have posted the full proof,so you are saying its correct.

Comment: Yes, eventhough it is not written very readable.

Comment: @sorry :),screen captured

Comment: You have to know that inverses are unique (which is an easy task to show) so that if $a*b=b*a= e$ then $a^{-1}=b$ and $b^{-1} = a$.

Comment: yeah, i proved it using left cancellation $a*e1=a*e2$ so e1=e2

Comment: Left and right cancellation follows from the uniqueness. To prove the latter assume $b^{-1} = a = a'$. Then $a = a*e = a*(b*a') = (a*b)*a'=e*a'=a'$.

Comment: sorry the one i typed in was for unique identity element.Silly careless mistake.